# Microsoft Azure SSL Error

Tags: python-2.7, azure, openssl, ssl-certificate

I'm new with azure. I'm getting below error -

```
ssl.SSLError: [Errno 336265225] _ssl.c:351:
error:140B0009:SSL routines:SSL_CTX_use_PrivateKey_file:PEM lib
```

I am using source code from 'https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-python' and was executing a simple azure code by python:

```
from azure.servicemanagement import ServiceManagementService
subscription_id = 'my subscription id'
cert_file = '/root/mycert.pem'
sms = ServiceManagementService(subscription_id, cert_file)

locations = sms.list_locations()
for location in locations:
    print(location.name)
```

Why am I getting an error with `SSL_CTX_use_PrivateKey_file`?

I am stuck! Please, help me out. Thank you in advance

Comment: Three potential issues without seeing anything. First, the private key is *not* in PEM format. Second, its in Traditional format rather then PKCS #8 format (or vice-versa). Third, the private key is password protected. Unfortunately, we'd need to see your private key to say for sure (which is a bad idea).

Comment: This might be helpful: [Openssl pkcs8 default format gives RSA PRIVATE KEY](http://superuser.com/questions/606215/openssl-pkcs8-default-format-gives-rsa-private-key). Traditional/PKCS #8 format differ by `BEGIN PRIVATE KEY` and `BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY`.

Comment: I followed the following instructions-
Create two certificates, one for the server (a .cer file) and one for the client (a .pem file). To create the .pem file using [OpenSSL](http://www.openssl.org), execute this:
openssl req -x509 -nodes -days 365 -newkey rsa:1024 -keyout mycert.pem -out mycert.pem
To create the .cer certificate, execute this:
openssl x509 -inform pem -in mycert.pem -outform der -out mycert.cer
Then, you will need to upload the file to management portal(http://manage.windows.com).